# Show annual or monthly chart using google data studio

Tags: date, google-sheets, charts, google-visualization, looker-studio

I have data on the `date_created` of our members with `DDMMYYYY` format. I want my chart in `MMYYYY` format when I selected A year timeline or a few months' timelines. But I want my data in `DDMMYYYY` when I selected a month timeline. How could I do that?

I want my chart would be like this :

**Lifetime Timeline:**

[image: Lifetime Timeline]

**One-month Timeline:**

[image: One-month timeline]

I made this manually using 2 fields.

Comment: you can use the following option --> `hAxis.format` -- to change the format depending on the chart shown...

Comment: Could you please share a sample sheet of your issue so that we can manipulate it and check if our suggestions work for your case?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried changing the Granularity of your time field?

[image]